# Get key value of dictionary by index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, javascript-objects

I have a javascript dictionary object which has a pre-set keys that are defaulted to `0`. Then I need to loop through the elements of this dictionary by **index** and use the value of the key to set its value. Below is my code to make things easier to understand:

```
var _map = {
    'severity-normal': 0,
    'severity-minimal': 0,
    'severity-moderate': 0,
    'severity-severe': 0,
    'severity-highly-severe': 0
};

    mapSeverities: function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < _map.length; i++) {
            //get the key value, ex: severity-normal, by index (which would by i)
            var key = //retrieved key value
            _map[key] = this.data(key);
        }
    }
```

In other words, suppose we're dealing with C#, I want to get the `KeyValuePair` at a certain index, then access its `Key` and `Value` properties.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Objects do not have index orders in JavaScript, so `length` will not be available unless you use an `Array` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For object `_map`, you should use `for .. in`.

```
for (var key in _map) {
  _map[key] = this.data[key];
}
```

Answer (score 33):

You can also use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) like this

```
$.each(_map, function(key, value) { 
  // key is the key
  // value is the value
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/fBy5K/1/)