# Creating multi-level object from different key:value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of the sort mentioned below for around 5000 values. The values of x1,x2,x3 are random and may or may not have similarities. I want to club the data given in the array into one JSON object first grouped on the basis of Group, then on Block. Its sure that the values of Village will always be unique.
Given:

```
Array= [ 
    {Group:"A", Block:"Kansas", Village:"Little",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
    {Group:"A", Block:"Kansas", Village:"Whinging",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
    {Group:"A", Block:"Angeles", Village:"Surrey",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
    {Group:"B", Block:"York", Village:"Privet",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
    {Group:"B", Block:"Columbia", Village:"Drive",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
    {Group:"B", Block:"Yorkshire", Village:"Number",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
   ]
```

Want:

```
Obj={
     "A": {
           "Kansas":[
                     {Village:"Little",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12},
                     {Village:"Whinging",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
                    ],
           "Angeles":[
                     {Village:"Surrey",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
                    ]
            },
     "B": {
           "York":[
                     {Village:"Privet",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
                    ],
           "Columbia":[
                     {Village:"Drive",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
                    ],
           "Yorkshire":[
                     {Village:"Number",x1:12,x2:214,x3:12}
                    ]
            }
    }
```

I tried writing functions that do this but none seem to work and give me an output like the one I expect since the values x1,x2 and x3 are non-similar. Also, its not necessary that there are only 3 values. There may be 10 or 15 too.

Could any of you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using jQuery is really necessary here...
Plus, SinnerShanky said he didn't know if there are always three values (x1...xn), so this won't work.

Here's another solution :

```
var obj = {}

arr.forEach(function(v){
    var group = v.Group,
        block = v.Block,
        villageObj = {};
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(group)){
        obj[group] = {};
    }
    if(!obj[group].hasOwnProperty(block)){
        obj[group][block] = [];
    }
    villageObj = v; // You should properly clone the object if you don't want to modify your initial object
    delete(villageObj.Group);
    delete(villageObj.Block);
    obj[group][block].push(villageObj);
});
```

However, keep in mind that I used delete to get rid of Group and Block, so these properties will **also** be deleted in your initial Array.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9yNX/)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it somewhat simple, you can just iterate, check if a propery exists, then add to it, if not create it etc.

```
var Obj = {};

$.each(Array, function(_, obj) {
    var o = {}, G = obj.Group, B = obj.Block;

    $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
        if ( $.inArray(key, ['Group', 'Block']) == -1 ) o[key] = val;
    });

    if ( ! (G in Obj) ) Obj[G] = {};
    B in Obj[G] ? Obj[G][B].push(o) : Obj[G][B] = [o];
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kTnXV/6/)

Note that there's no guarantee of order in objects, only arrays, and this doesn't change the original array.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly, you are trying to get all the values of a dict (and merge them in some way). You may use $.each for this purpose.

[Get key value of dictionary by index in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894484/get-key-value-of-dictionary-by-index-in-jquery)